# PHP populate drop down list with SQL data

Tags: php, sql

I want to populate a drop down list with values from database.

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';

$filter=mysql_query("select distinct fuel_type from car");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
$options ="<option>" . $row['fuel_type'] . "</option>";

$menu="<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=''>
  <p><label>Filter</label></p>
    <select name='filter' id='filter'>
      " . $options . "
    </select>
</form>";

echo $menu;
}
?>
```

The issue is that I get two lists instead of one list with the values inside. Please advise

[image: drop down list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `$menu` from your loop:

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';

$options = '';
$filter=mysql_query("select distinct fuel_type from car");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
    $options .="<option>" . $row['fuel_type'] . "</option>";
}

$menu="<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=''>
  <p><label>Filter</label></p>
    <select name='filter' id='filter'>
      " . $options . "
    </select>
</form>";

echo $menu;

?>
```

Comment: You're probably missing the `.` in the while loop. Copy and paste my code and try again.

Answer (score 2):

`echo $menu;` should be outside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';

$filter=mysql_query("select distinct fuel_type from car");
$menu="
<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=''>
  <p><label>Filter</label></p>
    <select name='filter' id='filter'>";

// Add options to the drop down
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter))
{
  $menu .="<option>" . $row['fuel_type'] . "</option>";
}

// Close menu form
$menu = "</select></form>";

// Output it
echo $menu;
?>
```